# Nhibernate paging performance

Tags: performance, nhibernate

I have table that contains more than 12 millions of rows.

I need to index this rows using Lucene.NET (I need to perform initial indexing).

So I try to index in batch manner, by reading batch packets from sql (1000 rows per batch).

Here is how it looks:

```
public void BuildInitialBookSearchIndex()
{
            FSDirectory directory = null;
            IndexWriter writer = null;

            var type = typeof(Book);

            var info = new DirectoryInfo(GetIndexDirectory());

            //if (info.Exists)
            //{
            //    info.Delete(true);
            //}

            try
            {
                directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(Path.Combine(info.FullName, type.Name), true);
                writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (directory != null)
                {
                    directory.Close();
                }

                if (writer != null)
                {
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }

            var fullTextSession = Search.CreateFullTextSession(Session);

            var currentIndex = 0;
            const int batchSize = 1000;

            while (true)
            {
                var entities = Session
                    .CreateCriteria<BookAdditionalInfo>()
                    .CreateAlias("Book", "b")
                    .SetFirstResult(currentIndex)
                    .SetMaxResults(batchSize)
                    .List();

                using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (var entity in entities)
                    {
                        fullTextSession.Index(entity);
                    }

                    currentIndex += batchSize;

                    Session.Flush();
                    tx.Commit();
                    Session.Clear();
                }

                if (entities.Count < batchSize)
                    break;
     }
}
```

But, the operation times out when current index is bigger then 6-7 million. NHibernate Pagging throws time out.

Any suggestions, any other way in NHibernate to index this 12 millions of rows?

**EDIT:**

Probably I will implement the most peasant solution.

Because BookId is cluster index in my table and select occurs very fast by BookId, I am going to find max BookId and going through all records and index all of them them.

```
for (long = 0; long < maxBookId; long++)
{
   // get book by bookId
   // if book exist, index it
}
```

If you have any other suggestion, please reply yo this question.

Comment: which operation throws the timeout ? what happens if you reduce batch size ?

Comment: When current index is bigger than 5-6 millions Nhibernate Criteria returns timeout (because of SetFirstResult), I try with smaller batch size, it occurs again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of paging your whole data set, you could try to divide and conquer it. You said you had an index on book id, just change your criteria to return batches of books according to bounds of bookid :

```
var entities = Session
    .CreateCriteria<BookAdditionalInfo>()
    .CreateAlias("Book", "b")
    .Add(Restrictions.Gte("BookId", low))
    .Add(Restrictions.Lt("BookId", high))
    .List();
```

Where low and high are set like 0-1000, 1001-2000, etc